# Windows Phone 7: Recommended menu control?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

What is the best way to make a menu of options in wp7? (Not a context menu or app bar.) Currently I'm using a `ListBox` of strings, but I'm not sure if that's the way to go.

I'm also not entirely sure how to make make the `ListBox` entries respond to tapping such that they navigate to another page.

Answer (score 1):

For a simple menu I've used someting like the following several times.

```
<ListBox SelectionChanged="LinkSelected">
    <ListBoxItem Name="EnterCode" >
        <TextBlock Text="Enter Code"  />
    </ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem Name="Login" >
        <TextBlock Text="Login" />
    </ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem Name="Register" >
        <TextBlock Text="Register" />
    </ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

And then something like this in the event handler:

```
private void WelcomeLinkSelected(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is ListBox)
    {
        if ((sender as ListBox).SelectedIndex < 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        if ((sender as ListBox).SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/EnterCode.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }

        if ((sender as ListBox).SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Login.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }

        if ((sender as ListBox).SelectedIndex == 2)
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Register.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }

        // This is very important!
        (sender as ListBox).SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
}
```

If you do this, the last line in the event handler, which resets the SelectedIndex, is very important as it allows the same menu item to be selected multiple times in a row without first selecting another option.

Comment: Why all the `(sender as ListBox)` instead of just casting once?

Comment: @Rosarch  yes, you could just cast one. example was ripped out of some old code which was also doing lots fo other things.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a listener to the selection change event on the listbox, and then use the NavigationService to navigate wherever you want based on the selected item.